# Unable to nbconvert or save jupyter notebook as flex dashboard html

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I'm running `jupyter notebook` with python=3.9,pandas=1.2.5 (in a separate conda environment)
I installed `nbconvert`, `jupyter-flex` using `pip install` as given in [jupyter-flex-getting-started](https://jupyter-flex.danielfrg.com/getting-started/) within the conda environment
I could add page, section & card elements with the cell tags; but not getting the save-as option as referred in: [save-as-flex-dashboard](https://jupyter-flex.danielfrg.com/assets/img/getting-started/download-as.png)

Also tried to run `jupyter nbconvert --to flex dashboard_prototype_with_charts_data.ipynb --execute` but `--to flex` is not being recognized as valid format

Comment: I had logged it as a  git issue https://github.com/danielfrg/jupyter-flex/issues/88

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Daniel](https://github.com/danielfrg); I was able to upgrade to 0.6.5; D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pd125\share\jupyter\nbconvert\templates\flex is present as expected.
[more info @ github](https://github.com/danielfrg/jupyter-flex/issues/88)

Just posting below update, if others face similar issue:
Since git was not in my system path `pip install -U jupyter-flex` was failing to install the latest version; after adding git to system path, I could install latest jupyter-flex